# Borders playing up

Tags: tables

Would anyone know why my borders are not appearing properly:

[image]

I'm using the following code:

```
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|@{}}
        \toprule
        \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
        Posición & Función & Valores \\ \midrule
        &  & R para un Router \\ \cmidrule(l){3-3} 
        \multirow{-2}{*}{1} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Tipo de Equipo} & S para Switch ó Conmutador \\ \midrule
        2 & Función & Variara dependiendo del equipo \\ \midrule
        4-6 & Localización del Equipo & Tres primeras letras de la localización p. ej. Sevilla: SEV \\ \midrule
        8 & Ordenación de los equipos & Ascendente dependiendo de la fecha de instalación \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Nomenclatura para Equipos}\label{table:Equipos}
\end{table}
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: You are using the rules from package `booktabs` which discourages vertical lines in tables. You could see it as a bug, but it is rather a design decision. Better use LaTeX's regular horizontal rules, if you want also vertical rules.

Comment: If you really need this, then change `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` to get rid of the vertical spacings. I don't recomment it, however

Comment: @Johannes_B so instead of using '\midrule' I should use '\hrule'?

Comment: `\hline` and `\cline`.

Comment: thank you so much both of you for the help. Finally my tables looking as I wanted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem ocurred from using booktabs insted of regular horizontal rules. Implementing this change the code will look such as follows:

```
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|@{}}
        \hline
        \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
        Posición & Función & Valores \\ \hline
        &  & R para un Router \\ \cline{3-3} 
        \multirow{-2}{*}{$1$} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Tipo de Equipo} & S para Switch ó Conmutador \\ \hline
        $2$ & Función & Variara dependiendo del equipo \\ \hline
        \numrange{4}{6} & Localización del Equipo & Tres primeras letras de la localización p. ej. Sevilla: SEV \\ \hline
        $8$ & Ordenación de los equipos & Ascendente dependiendo de la fecha de instalación \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Nomenclatura para Equipos}\label{table:Equipos}
\end{table}
```

Thank you to @Johannes_B and @Christian Hupfer for their help and answering so quickly.